# Debug Java .jar with gdb

Tags: java, debugging, gdb

I have Java application and I export it to runnable .jar application. Can I debug that .jar with gdb ( for some reasons I cannot debug my source code from Eclipse ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [ibm tutorial](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rt.doc.10/diag/problem_determination/linux_gdb.html) fits to your need and here is [more (on gnu)](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/gdb.html)

```
gdb <Java Executable> <system dump>
break linenumber
```

Comment: Both links are dead.